# Using pyautogui with multiple monitors

Tags: python, automation

I'm trying to use the pyautogui module for python to automate mouse clicks and movements. However, it doesn't seem to be able to recognise any monitor other than my main one, which means i'm not able to input any actions on any of my other screens, and that is a huge problem for the project i am working on.

I've searched google for 2 hours but i can't find any straight answers on whether or not it's actually possible to work around. If anyone could either tell me that it is or isn't possible, tell me how to do it if it is, or suggest an equally effective alternative (for python) i would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible! Use this code to determine where your mouse is registering on the screen:

```
import pyautogui

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nDone.')
```

This should be run from a command prompt. The output will be nonsensical if run through IDLE.

Comment: Ok this solved the initial problem of getting my mouse coordinates, so thank you. However, i still can't input any mouse activity onto any of the other monitors because pyautogui is still only responding to coordinates within 0x0 to 1920x1080. Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't giving me any error, the command prompt is behaving as if nothing is wrong. but when i enter a value outside of the current monitors dimensions, it moves the mouse as close to that value as possible. so for example. if i put in (-1000, 0), then the mouse will be moved to the very top left of the monitor, as if i entered (0, 0)

Comment: Damn, that didn't work either. i did more tests and it does turn out that pyautogui CAN recognise that my cursor is outside the range of the main monitor. but any movement at all outside the main monitors range is completely blocked. This is so frustrating

Comment: I made a room for more discussion, so this post doesn't have too many comments:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188078/python

Comment: Unfortunately i only made an account today, so i don't have enough reputation to post i the room. However to answer the question you posted there, i'm just running these commands through the python cmd and IDLE.

Comment: I thought I gave you permissions, but I guess not. I don't know how to use the chat site very well yet. I think it would be helpful if you edit your initial post to include your current code (a relevant snip), so people here can see what you are trying to do. Also, accepting an answer to this question will give you the "scholar" badge which I think would give you some reputation points. Maybe that would be enough to use the chat? I don't know.

Comment: According to the [PyAutoGUI FAQ](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#faq-frequently-asked-questions), multi-monitor setup is not supported. Only the primary monitor is handled.

Comment: @Joe Pringle did you ever find a workaround for PyAutoGUI's lack of support for multiple monitors?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is clear but I subtracted an extended monitor's horizontal resolution from 0 because my 2nd monitor is on the left of my primary display. That allowed me to avoid the out of bounds warning. my answer probably isn't the clearest but I figured I would chime in to let folks know it actually can work.

Comment: Please also explain the thought behind subtracting the resolution. It may add much needed clarity to your answer.